# mysql table structure with xml column?

Tags: mysql, xml, data-structures

This is not exactly a question, but I am just looking for an opinion on this matter.

I am doing my first work with a company. They asked me to optimize their mysql db full text search.

Now, as soon as I saw the database structure, I literally changed face expression.

It is a car parts database, and they have like 1 table and 3 columns: ID, part_number, xml.

Am I just stupid not to understand this, or are they for putting ALL, and I say ALL the information about each different product inside an ENORMOUS xml text? I just don't get it, and want a clarification. Could they have not put each different information regarding that product (say like: color, size, manufacturer, etc.) inside each different column? Or use an object based unrelational DB (like Mongo)? Is it a 'normal' practice to use this to enable a "full-text" search on an XML text to return the relevant item?

Please enlighten me, either I am really stupid and don't get it, or that DB is a complete non-sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use something like http://sqlfiddle.com/ to describe your question more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem they get is that the number of attributes for different parts is a never ending list, some of them are common for many parts, some of them are not. If you attempt to put a column per attribute then you end up with thousands of columns - there are some technolgoies to deal with that in some RDBMS - sparse columns / tables.

An alternative is to normalize out the attributes onto an attribute table where you are storing part_id, attribute, value - which becomes a very large key-value table, and will rapidly grow in cardinality - and potentially some of these values are different types, and could be quite large. They will also duplicate, so you could normalize out again and then realize you have gone down a rabbit hole of painful performance and horrid scenarios where you have multiple value fields for different types or have to store a variant data type.

The final alternative is to FTS a field / store XML - which is what you found someone chose.

Someone made a choice, perhaps first time you may see it in an RDBMS, but probably not the last - whilst you are in a relational storage - consider how you would of done it differently to the original author (within the restriction of an RDBMS).

It's always a nasty problem to store attribute information for items with disparate attributes - I've seen all three options taken by people in the past.

Comment: Isn't it better to figure out at least a number of common and most frequently used search criterias and to keep the rest as xml? Still there is name, manufacturer, dimensions, weight, cost for every item.

Comment: Potentially, but these columns can rapidly expand out and often do. It's a YMMV situation and I wouldn't make a choice without knowing what data I faced. If the XML conforms to a fixed schema it can at least be easier to manage, it isn't clear from the question whether that is even true.

Comment: do you think that using sphinx for full-text search, in this case with 70mb of xml data, would be a viable solution? This is what I am thinking currently to enable a fast search.

Comment: I can't tell you what's viable and what isn't. You know your constraints, SLAs, data, queries etc - ultimately it is your call on what is viable.

Comment: The thing is that this data does not change, it's just there, used as a "repository" for the manufacturer to get the part name and be able to buy it from the producer. I was thinking that using Mongo by putting the properties of the elements in "tags", as explained here http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo would have been a better aternative. What do you think?

Comment: I have to ask the question - what is the catalyst to change the current implementation, because you do not like it? or because there is a valid business reason such as SLA breaches. Changing production code, causing QA efforts etc has to be justified.

Comment: You know why I am asking you, because they don't know either. They called me to fix their work, but it's ok anyway. I just wanted to know if it was an usual practice. You answered my question perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well it really looks kinda stupid the way you described it. It's hard to say anything about modifying the data structure without knowing anything about it, but I think that anything is better then full-text search.